# React Beautiful DND & Redux: Using a single Redux store, but still reorder cards between lists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, drag-and-drop, react-redux

I'm building what is essentially a Trello clone using React and Redux. Thanks to @Sagiv b.g, I've got logic in place to allow users to create multiple `<Board/>`, `<List/>` and `<Card/>` instances using a single Redux store.

But that logic breaks down when I want to move `<Card/>` components between different `<List/>`.

**Example**

If I create two lists, one called "To Do" and one called "Done", my Redux logic matches the separate React `<List/>` component instances to the correct `<Board/>` instance using my `boards()` reducer like so:

```
case ADD_LIST:
  return state.map(board => {
    if (board.id !== action.boardId) return board;
    return {
      ...board,
      lists: lists(board.lists, action)
    };
  });
```

If I then create a card in my "To Do" list called "Finish Kanban project", the logic is basically the same in Redux for matching the correct `<Card/>` instance to the correct `<List/>` instance, except it happens in the `lists()` reducer:

```
case ADD_CARD:
  return state.map(list => {
    if (list.listId !== action.listId) return list;
    return {
      ...list,
      cards: cards(list.cards, action)
    };
  });
```

So far so good! But if I want to ***move*** the card I just created from the "To Do" list to the "Done" list, I can't quite figure out the logic with React Beautiful DND and Redux combined.

React Beautiful DND wants to reorder the **entire** array, which means I need to update my array of cards in Redux accordingly. So I'm stuck on how to take a card out of one list and move it to another list using my current Redux logic.

Thanks for any direction. I'm ready to abandon Redux or React Beautiful DND altogether, but wanted to see if anyone has any ideas on how to make it work.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with React Beautiful DND API but in general you would need to hook up to the drag / drop events and when an item leaves it's group and dropped in another group you can dispatch a `"REMOVE_ITEM"` action to remove it from its former group and then invoke the `"ADD_ITEM"` to join it to the new group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working through the same issue. If you watch the free egghead videos for React Beautiful DnD: https://egghead.io/courses/beautiful-and-accessible-drag-and-drop-with-react-beautiful-dnd you will see that regardless of whether you are using redux, you need to write logic in your `onDragEnd` handler to update the state. In the video, he is using the `useState()` hook to manage the state of his lists. In your case, you would emulate what he does but do it in redux by dispatching an action. You can use the same state shape and basically the same code as what is shown in the video. You just need to do it in redux.